# Update records from access database selected row java swing

Tags: java, swing

How To Fix error? I am trying Update the Jtable row data and microsoft access database but it occurred issue.

> It Update all rows from the access table instead selected row.

can anyone fix the error? or show me code for it?

```
**My code is**

DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
         String id, fname, lname;
       connection = ConnectionDb.getConnection();
       try{

           String value1=txtFname.getText();
           String value2=txtLname.getText();
           PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("Update Student SET FirstName = '"+value1+"' , LastName ='"+value2+"'  where ID = +id");


              preparedStatement.execute();

     int i = jTable1.getSelectedRow();

       if(i >= 0)
       {
         jTable1.setValueAt(txtFname.getText(), i, 0);
           jTable1.setValueAt(txtLname.getText(), i, 1);
       }else
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
       }
        connection.commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code:

**First:** You are not specifying an `Id` in the `Where` clause properly. So the update is updating everything.

```
// Your "Where" means basically "Where 1 = 1"
PreparedStatement preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("Update Student SET FirstName = '"+value1+"' , LastName ='"+value2+"'  where ID = +id");
```

**Second:** It's better to use parameters instead of simply concatenating your variables. Here is how you could do it:

```
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    String id, fname, lname;
    connection = ConnectionDb.getConnection();
    try{

        String value1=txtFname.getText();
        String value2=txtLname.getText();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("Update Student SET FirstName = ? , LastName = ?  where ID = ?");

        preparedStatement.setString(1, value1);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, value2);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, id);

        preparedStatement.execute();

        // Code continues..
        ....
```

**Third:** Where is your ID value? You created the variable in the second line but you didn't set any value there. You need to retrieve the value and use it in order to update your `Student` data.

Comment: I  did not create ID field in my Add record form.  can i update without Id.

Comment: @user1762748 You need to use something so you know which item you need to update. An ID is normally used. If you have any other unique key you can use it